# ASP.net - Dynamically displaying controls

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I am developing Quiz project. In DetailsView I want to display  the Question and answers.

The number of answers vary for question to question.Say example

```
1 ) C# Support

   (i)  Generics
   (ii) LINQ
   (iii)EntLib  

2 ) Find the odd one
    (i)  DB2
    (ii) Oracle
    (iii)MS-Access 
    (iv) Sql Server
    (v)  Javascript
```

so i can not fix the number of radio buttons.Some questions may have multiple answers.so i need to display checkboxes instead of radio buttons.

My Question is how to generate Radio Buttons or Checkboxed Dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a RadioButtonList or CheckBoxList for each question and use its Items collection to add the answers.

Very simple example in C#:

```
class Question
{
    public string QuestionText;
    public List<string> Answers;
}

protected void AddQuestionsToContainer(Control container, List<Question> questions)
{
    foreach (Question q in questions)
    {
        var qt = new Label();
        qt.Text = q.QuestionText;
        container.Controls.Add(qt);

        var rbl = new RadioButtonList();

        foreach (string answer in q.Answers)
        {
            rbl.Items.Add(new ListItem(answer));
        }

        container.Controls.Add(rbl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your question more specifically is how to decide which quiz question has multiple answers.

If I'm correct than you need to have an extra column like `isMultipleAnswers BIT` in the table in DB (or whatever the source is you need to have a flag for each question), and handle a event for the DetailView like DataBinding, check the value for this field, based on that either add RadioButtonList or CheckBoxList.

Hope this helps!

BTW, why aren't you using Repeater??